# Delete elements from div before adding new data

Tags: javascript, html

I want to delete everything from the container `w2`.

Then, place new data in `w2`.

my code:

```js
document.getElementById('w2').innerHTML = '';
    db.collection('arraylist').where('id','==',activeID).get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            var subgroups = doc.get('groups');
            console.log(subgroups);
            var j = 0;
            for(j;j < subgroups.length;j++){

                var sgroupName = subgroups[j];
                var sframe = document.getElementById('subgroupsframe');
                var sgroupholder = document.createElement('div');
                sframe.appendChild(sgroupholder);
                .... unnecessary code below
```

My code just leaves `w2` blank instead of removing the data, then adding it. It should display `sgroupholder` (which does have content, just not in this snippet.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean it should display `sgroupholder` inside `w2`?

Comment: @WaisKamal yes, after deleting the previously shown `sgroupholder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created `sgroupholder`, but did not append it to any element. All you have to do is append `sgroupholder` to `sframe`.

```
sframe.appendChild(sgroupholder);
```

Comment: sorry, I forgot to paste that in: `sframe` is inside `w2` by default. This still doesn't work. I've updated my post.

Comment: So, you want `sframe`, not `sgroupholder` to be inside `w2`. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. But `sframe` is already in `w2`. I want `groupholder` to be in `sframe`, which is a child of `w2`. sframe is there.

Comment: I've realised what my problem was - it's very stupid: I didn't realise I was deleting `sframe` with `.innerHTML`. I added code to add `sframe` back.